# Angular 2 ways binding with one field enabled and the other disabled

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, angular-material

I am having 2 fields in my angular application. I am using data binding for these two fields because these 2 fields have same data. However, in one of the field I need to enabled it and the other I need to disable it.

I found that both of my field is disabled now when I `disabled="true"` in one of the fields. Any solutions to only disabled one of the field and the other of the field is enabled?

The following is my source code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label>{{ 'company-info.performance.Red' | translate }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="less than %" [(ngModel)]="data.nonprfmCustT1" name="nonprfmCustT1">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
          <label>{{ 'company-info.performance.Amber' | translate }}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [disabled]="true" type="number" placeholder="higher than or Equal %" [(ngModel)]="data.nonprfmCustT1" name="nonprfmCustT1">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="number" min="data.nonprfmCustT1" max="100" placeholder="less than %" [(ngModel)]="data.nonprfmCustT2" name="nonprfmCustT2">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Next, how can I set min value of nonprfmCustT2 must be greater than nonprfmCustT1?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? **next** what do you mean, please?

Comment: Next, in my [(ngModel)]="data.nonprfmCustT2"  field data validation  must be greater than data.nonprfmCustT1 value

Comment: From my html, I have 2 rows. For the first row [(ngModel)]="data.nonprfmCustT1" is the same as second row [(ngModel)]="data.nonprfmCustT1". But second row [(ngModel)]="data.nonprfmCustT1" I want to disabled it.

Comment: Ohh, I finally got your point now....perhaps you should update your question with your comments' info